# Gradle - Eclipse Project Nature

Tags: gradle

How would I add something to the project nature of the Eclipse project generated by Gradle.

I want to add the following:

```
<nature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</nature>
<nature>edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse.findbugsNature</nature>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured this one out.

Add the following your build file:

```
eclipse {
  project {
    natures 'com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature'
  }
}
```

[Gradle Eclipse Project Docs](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseProject.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click your java project -> configure -> add Gradle nature.
2. Select window -> show view -> other... select Gradle tasks.
3. Expand your project in 'Gradle tasks' -> build setup, right click "init" and run.